# How to condense an array of integers in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array of integers: `<1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14>`, that I would like to join together in this format: `<1-3, 9-11, 14>`.

I'm new to PHP and tried doing this by looping through the array:

```
function pasteTogether($val)
    {
        $newVals = array();
        $min = $val[0];
        $max = $val[1];
        $counter = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++)
        {
            if ($val[$i + 1] === $val[$i] + 1)
            {
                $max = $val[$i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                $tempVal = $min."-".$max;
                $newVals[$counter] = $tempVal;
                $counter++;
                $min = $val[$i];
            }
        }
        return $newVals;
    }
```

However, when I run this code, I get <1-3, 3-11, 11-11, 14-14>

Comment: For me, output looks like this: `Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/ehm.php on line 10`, `print_r` gives this: `Array ( [0] => 1-3 [1] => 3-11 [2] => 11-11 )`

Comment: Forgot to add, that's after fixing the iterator (you increment `$val` intstead of `$i`)

Comment: Wow I'm a doof. Well, I guess I still have some work to do since the output isn't quite right. The $val thing was a boneheaded mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ../learning.php on line 36**

Because the for loop never ends you increment $val instead of $i

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14);


function pasteTogether($val)
{
    $newVals = array();
    $min = $val[0];
    $max = $val[1];
    $counter = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++)
    {
        if ($val[$i + 1] === $val[$i] + 1)
        {
            $max = $val[$i + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            $tempVal = $min."-".$max;
            $newVals[$counter] = $tempVal;
            $counter++;
            $min = $val[$i];
        }
    }
    return $newVals;
}

pasteTogether($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this interesting problem and found another solution. So, if anyone is interested:

```
$arr=array(1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18);
$v0=$dif=null;$rows=array();

foreach ($arr as $i => $v) {
 if ($dif!=($d=($v-$i))){
   if ($v0) $rows[]="$v0-".$arr[$i-1];
   $v0=$v;
   $dif=$d;
 }
}
$rows[]="$v0-".($d==$dif?$arr[$i]:$v0);

print_r($rows);
```

I added a few numbers to the array and the result is this:

```
$rows = Array
(
    [0] => 1-3
    [1] => 9-11
    [2] => 14-16
    [3] => 18-18
)
```

You can find a little demo here: http://rextester.com/ABC25608

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function pasteTogether($val)
{
    $compacted = [];
    $min       = null;
    $max       = null;

    $format = function ($a, $b) {
        return ($a < $b ? "$a-$b" : $a);
    };

    foreach ($val as $current) {
        if ($min === null) {
            $min = $current;
            $max = $current - 1;
        }

        if ($current == $max + 1) {
            $max++;
        } else {
            $compacted[] = $format($min, $max);
            $min         = $current;
            $max         = $current;
        }
    }

    $compacted[] = $format($min, $max);

    return $compacted;
}

echo '<', implode(', ', pasteTogether([1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 14])), '>';
```

Output:
<1-3, 9-11, 14>